# Delta Table read performance when using delta-rs Python API?

Tags: python, delta-lake, delta-rs

I'm trying to read `Delta Table` using delta-rs library (Python).

The table has millions of records and we wanted to read it frequently using `Rest API` call(only specific records, based on request).

So, i was checking the `delta-rs` library. Since it has millions of records the read performance is not good..

Its reading the entire table and convert it as Pandas DF( before i can filter based on my request).

Is there a way to read only the records what i need instead of reading entire table then filter ( like `column pruning` , `predicate pushdown` etc)

**Update:** i followed this issue (https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/631) and able to get good performance by converting DeltaTable to PyArrow Dataset and then using Duckdb to filter.